# How to return multiple values from shared prefrences in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to get multiple values from shared preferences. I have created a page on this page several bool values are exist i want that when user checks that values and goes to other page then he will come back then all values state will be preserve.

Comment: Kindly share the code snippet you're discussing so we can properly help you solve the issue .

Comment: If you want to easily serialize many values in shared_preferences you should check out this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/pref_dessert

Answer (score 1):

You should be make object and store into share-preference
For Example:

```
class Data
{
List<bool> list;
Data(this.list);

factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DataToJson(this);
}
```

Store Data in Sharepreference

```
 await SharePreferencesHelper.getInstant().setString('key_data',jsonEncode(data.toJson()));
```

data is object of Data class and it contain list of bool data

Get data from sharepreference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String data = prefs.getString('key_data');

    if (data == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return Data.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));
    }
```